# Map/HashMap Casting?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

So I have a method, `setContainerSummaryMap`, which takes in a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`.

I also have a `HashMap<Long, HashMap<String, Integer>>`, called `contIdDestQuanMapSoFar`, which I am going to convert into a `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>` with a `HashMap<Long, String>`, named `contIdToScanIdMap`, that maps the keys to one another. This method is below:

```
public HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> convertContSummaryMap() {
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> toRet = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
    for (Entry<Long, HashMap<String, Integer>> entry : contIdDestQuanMapSoFar.entrySet()) {
        toRet.put(contIdToScanIdMap.get(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue());
    }
    return toRet;
}
```

The problem is, when I call the method `setContainerSummaryMap(currentPlan.convertContSummaryMap())`, I get an error, saying that it is not applicable for the arguments `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>`. How would I modify the datatypes for this to work? Thanks.

Comment: A `HashMap<Map>` is not the same as a `HashMap<HashMap>`.  Only one of them can hold a `TreeMap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine your `setContainerSummaryMap` method:

```
public void setContainerSummaryMap(Map<String, ? extends Map<String, Integer>> map)
```

or, as Louis already suggested change the return type of your `convertContSummaryMap` to match:

```
public HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>> convertContSummaryMap()
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this work, the type of `toRet` must be `HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>`.  As @SLaks stated, a `HashMap<String, Map>` is not the same as a `HashMap<String, HashMap>`.

Of course, the `Map`s you'll actually put into it will still be `HashMap`s.